# Where can I find company filing information in Singapore?

Tags: investing, stocks, singapore

I found that in the US one can take a look and research company filing information (such as 10-K, 10-Q etc) a the [SEC](http://www.sec.gov/) before they invest in a company. For Singapore I only find [SGX](http://www.sgx.com/), and couldn't find related information such as company fillings in there.

But as I live in Singapore, I want to know

> 1) the resources for such company filing information available
>   for Singapore Companies and related stock information specifically.

And most the books or resources that I am learning are for US. And SG system may be different from US,

> 2) I want to know what are the specific terms and usages in Singapore
>   (such as 10-K, 10-K for US)
>
> 3) Other related need to know terms and usages for Singapore Stock
>   System.

Comment: first step: the regulator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are refering to company's financial reports and offerings, the required source for companies to disclose the information is the SGX website (www.sgx.com) under the Company Disclosure tab.

This includes annual statements for the last 5 years, prospectus for any shares/debentures/buy back/etc which is being offered, IPO offers and shareholders meetings.

You may also find it useful to check the Research section of the SGX website where some of the public listed companies have voluntarily allowed independent research firms to monitor their company for a couple of years and produce a research report.

If you are referring to filings under the Companies Act, these can be found at the Accounting and Regulatory Authority (ACRA) website (www.acra.gov.sg) and you can also purchase extracts of specific filings under the ACRA iShop.

To understand the Singapore public listing system and the steps to public listing, you may find it useful to purchase one of the resource documents available for Singapore law, finance, tax and corporate secretaryship which are sold by CCH (www.cch.com.sg). Specifically for public listing the Singapore Annotated Listing Manual may help.

It is common practice for companies here to employ law firms and research firms to do the majority of this research instead of doing it themselves which I one of the reasons this information is online but perhaps not so visible.

I hope I have understood your question correctly!

Comment: imm.. seem like the presentation of Annual Report by Companies [ under Company Disclosure tab from SGX website] are quit varied depend on each company. But I can still find some useful information in there. For some companies, I can only find for one year, not all five years.  For ACRA and CCH, I think I need to buy info if I want to browse the data (I gonna skip it for this moment).(Q 2,3) : Is there anyway that I learn those specific terms and usages in Singapore for free via online or any good books that I can borrow from library ?

Comment: There are certain required fields and information which companies needs to report but this is relatively high level and the format of the report is not 100% mandated so you should expect to find quite a variety.

Comment: For companies which have only been listed a year ago, their pre-listing information will not be available on SGX but you can find some data in their prospective and IPO documents. It is hard to recommend a resource for specific terms without knowing your actual use case but you can try the FAQ glossary terms on SGX or borrow a Singapore Exchange Factbook from the library, may help.